# Cannot use object of type Entity\X as array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have little problem, I have no idea what's wrong with my code :/

```
$ilosc = $_POST["ilosc"];

        $recipe = new Recipe();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Recipe');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p.id')->where('p.nazwa = :nazwa AND p.adres = :adres')->setParameters(array('nazwa' => $_POST["nazwaprzepisu"], 'adres' => $_POST["adresprzepisu"]))->getQuery();
        $test = $query->getResult();
        $id = $test[0]['id'];


        $idprod = $_POST['idprod'];
        $iloscprod = $_POST['iloscprod'];


        for ($i = 0; $i < $ilosc; $i++)
        {
            $ingredient = new Ingredient();
            $repositorying = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Ingredient');
            $query = $repositorying->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p')->where('p.przepis_id = :id AND p.produkt_id = :idprod')->setParameters(array('id' => $id, 'idprod' => $idprod[$i]))->getQuery();
            $result = $query->getResult();

            if(!$result)
            {
                $ingredient->setProduktId($idprod[$i]);
                $ingredient->setPrzepisId($id);
                $ingredient->setIlosc($iloscprod[$i]);

            }
            else
            {
                $nowailosc = $result[0]['ilosc'] + $iloscprod[$i];
                $stareid = $result[0]['id'];

                echo "kokoko";

            }
            $em->persist($ingredient);
            $em->flush();   
        }
```

I have problem with those two lines:

```
$nowailosc = $result[0]['ilosc'] + $iloscprod[$i];
$stareid = $result[0]['id'];
```

I get an error:
"Fatal error: Cannot use object of type My\MainBundle\Entity\Ingredient as array in". 
Somebody have idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I had to use:

```
$nowailosc = $result[0]->getIlosc() + $iloscprod[$i];
$stareid = $result[0]->getId();
```